# How to create header for List in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, list, uitableview, header, swiftui

I want to implement a header to a List in SwiftUI. I can do this using ScrollView but I want the properties of List (like lazy loading). There is a SectionHeader but that stays fixed on the top until the user scrolls to the end of that section and I don't want this behavior. I just want to scroll the whole view.

Is there a way of achieving this using SwiftUI?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you really just want a custom cell at the top of the List.

Just use Sections.  If you make it a plain section, with one entry, it will appear at the top, and scroll away when the view scrolls.

```
    List {
        Section() {
            YourCustomRowThatLooksLikeAHeader()
        }

        Section() {
            // Normal list stuff
            ForEach(offers, id: \.self) { offer in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: DetailView(offer: offer)
            ) {
                HStack {
                    Image(offer.offerThumbnail ?? "")
                    Text("\(offer.shortInfo ?? "")")
                }
            }
                
        }
    }
```